What color OpenType/TrueType fonts rely on a version 0 (not version 1) 'COLR' table?
The original OpenType/TrueType 'COLR' table specification was a simple table (version 0) that allowed only for drawing a color glyph using a glyph outline and a solid color taken from the 'CPAL' table.
The later 'COLR' version 1 format was introduced to allow color base glyphs to be composed of collections of other glyph outlines, each with either solid or gradient colors, along with interspersed linear transformations.
Modern color fonts, such as Noto Color Emoji, contain both a 'COLR' and an 'SVG ' table.  Either table is available, and each draws the same image for a given base glyph.  But this emoji font's 'COLR' table only uses the more flexible version 1 format.
Are there older color OpenType/TrueType fonts (presumably non-emoji), either free or at low cost, that were/are built using the 'COLR' version 0 format?  Such a font file would be very helpful for testing some OpenType font table parsing code.

There's a good chance to find legacy versions in a GIThub repo like https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts although the naming conventions may not be self explanatory

This isn't really a programming question, it's effectively an off-topic request for software recommendations. Good question to ask over on https://typedrawers.com, but not as good a question for asking here.

The twemoji-colr repo has a COLR v0 font. You could also use nanoemoji to build a COLRv0 font for testing.
